# Why does schema data type changes after copying same schema to another dataFrame in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a schema which has all of its columns as `StringType` and I am creating a dataFrame from here

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialSource/MAIN")
val header = rdd.filter(_.contains("Source.organizationId")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
val schema = StructType(header.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "_"), StringType)).toSeq)
val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(!_.contains("Source.organizationId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schema)
```

Now I am creating another dataFrame by copying the schema but the data type in the new schema changes I dont know why

How can I retain data same data type?

Here is how I am creating new dataFrame

```
val temp = dfType.select(dfType.columns.filter(x => !x.equals("sr:Auditors")).map(x => col(x).as(x.replace("_", "Source_").replace("sr:", ""))): _*)

//temp.show(false)

val dataMain = df1resultFinal.withColumn("TimeStamp", lit(null: String))

val dfReorder = dataMain.columns.toSeq

val tempReorder=temp.select(dfReorder.map(c => col(c)): _*)

val diff = schema.fieldNames.diff(tempReorder.schema.fieldNames)

val finaldf = diff.foldLeft(tempReorder){(temp2df, colName) => temp2df.withColumn(colName, lit("null"))}
```

I can cast each columns and make it as same schema .But is there anyway to retain same data type without casting ?

Comment: You haven't used schema totally. You have just used the field names of old dataframe to select from the new dataframe. you haven't changed the datatype of the new dataframe

Comment: @RameshMaharjan `schema.fieldNames` will give us only fields name with default data type

Comment: schema.fieldNames would just give you array of column names :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan got it this is working for me then `val casted = finaldf.columns.foldLeft(finaldf)((current, c) => current.withColumn(c, col(c).cast("String")))`

Comment: great :) you are doing great with foldLeft :)